# Jquery 2 click Function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide and show my footer navbar but i wanted to change the chevron icon , when the navbar is hidden chevron up to be displayed and when navbar shown chevron down show therefore i tried removing a class .bottom-action and add one class .bottom-action2 and when the 2nd one is clicked inverse all settings but it is not working as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bottom-action").click(function(){
        $(".bottom-navbar").slideToggle("slow");
       $(".down").css("display","none");
       $(".up").css("display","block");
       $(".bottom-action").removeClass('bottom-action').addClass("bottom-action2");
         
    });

$(".bottom-action2").click(function(){
        $(".bottom-navbar").slideToggle("slow");
       $(".up").css("display","none");
       $(".down").css("display","block");
       $(".bottom-action2").removeClass('bottom-action2').addClass("bottom-action");
         
    });



});
```

```css
.bottom-navbar{
  position: fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: #E4E4E4;
padding-top: 3px;
border-top: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
z-index: 7000;
}

.bottom-navbar .item{

  margin-left: 22px;
margin-right: 22px;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-action{position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 10%;
background-color: #EEE;
color: #000;
z-index: 7002;
background: transparent;

}

.bottom-action2{position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 10%;
background-color: #EEE;
color: #000;
z-index: 7002;
background: transparent;

}

.bottom-action .down{}
.bottom-action .up{display: none;}
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="bottom-navbar">
    <div class='container'><div class='item'>Compare</div></div>
</div>

<div class='bottom-action'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down down'></span> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up up'></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(e){
    //jour code
});
```

Instead of :

```
$('myButton').click(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that at the time of binding the event there is no bottom-action2 element in your DOM.
Funnily enough, this would work:

```
$(".bottom-action").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("bottom-action")){
      // do one thing
  }
  else if if($(this).hasClass("bottom-action2")){
     // do the other thing
  }
}
```

But as @Béranger pointed out, using a handler on a higher level would be the cleaner solution. In your case something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.bottom-action', function(e){
   // do one thing
});

$(document).on('click', '.bottom-action2', function(e){
   // do the other thing
});
```

Comment: Voted up for expiclationns